# Reporting effects of interest with and without a confounder: Is it reasonable?

Tags: causality, confounding, reporting

Suppose that we have the following situation. With a predictor $X$ and a response variable $Y$, plus a confounder $C$, we consider two models: one is

$Y \sim N(\alpha_0+\beta_0 X, ~\sigma_0^2)$

and the other is

$Y \sim N(\alpha_1+\beta_1 X + \gamma_1 C, ~\sigma_1^2)$

Would you consider it a good practice to report both the estimations of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ to observe the impact of the confounder C? If so, what is the rationale especially from the causal inference perspective?

Comment: Reporting both can't hurt, although it may not be necessary depending on the case. If this is a setting where the confounding relationship is clear and lots of people have run this regression before, you may not need it. If the confounder isn't obvious or you think it's central to the story, I'd definitely report both. If in doubt, reporting more (e.g. in the appendix) is probably the better choice than leaving out information.

Comment: @Scriddie I agree with your suggestion of adopting a nuanced reporting strategy. Thanks a lot!